# Animation not working with calculated CSS variables

Tags: css, svg, css-animations, svg-animate, css-variables

I want animate the property **stroke-dasharray** of SVG circle with CSS var.

In green, the animations are correct and animate **continuously and smoothly**.
In red, the animation is incorrect because it animate **in steps**.

I think there is a problem with calculated CSS variable, but I don't understand what.
We can see that the animation with the square is correct even though it uses the calculated CSS var.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

svg {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

circle.good {
  stroke: green;
  stroke-width: 5;
  animation: good-dash 2s ease-in-out infinite;
}

circle.bad {
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 5;
  animation: bad-dash 2s ease-in-out infinite;
  --stroke-dasharray: 10;
}

.square {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  animation: good-roll 2s infinite ease-in-out both;
  position: relative;
  --left: 1;
}

@keyframes good-dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 1, 10;
  }
  50% {
    stroke-dasharray: 1, 5;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 1, 10;
  }
}

@keyframes bad-dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 1, var(--stroke-dasharray);
  }
  50% {
    stroke-dasharray: 1, calc(var(--stroke-dasharray) / 2);
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 1, var(--stroke-dasharray);
  }
}

@keyframes good-roll {
  0% {
    left: calc(var(--left) * 1px);
  }
  50% {
    left: calc(var(--left) * 50px);
  }
  100% {
    left: calc(var(--left) * 1px);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="25 25 50 50">
  <circle class="good" cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="none"/>
</svg>
<svg viewBox="25 25 50 50">
  <circle class="bad" cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="none"/>
</svg>
<div class="square"></div>
```

Comment: in what browser?

Comment: @TemaniAfif what's written in the question shouldn't work in any browser. It might do in Chrome as that does seem to have a non-standard calc implementation. Safari, Firefox and w3c are more strict.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Units are mandatory in calc expressions that involve things that are not naturally unitless and really you should try to use them everywhere as CSS mostly demands them.

- opacity is a genuinely unitless property, it's just a [`<number>` in the  specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/masking.html#OpacityProperty).
- [stroke-dasharray](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/painting.html#StrokeProperties) however is not unitless its either a `<length>` or a `<percentage>`
- SVG has a special 'legacy' rule that says that some properties unique to SVG that would normally require units can be written without units.

When it comes to calc expressions though that specific SVG rule allowing the omission of units does not apply and [everything that should have a unit, must have a unit](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/4874#issuecomment-614138114). Chrome has not currently implemented this requirement but I expect they will at some point.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

svg {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

circle.good {
  stroke: green;
  stroke-width: 5;
  animation: good-dash 2s ease-in-out infinite;
}

circle.bad {
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 5;
  animation: bad-dash 2s ease-in-out infinite;
  --stroke-dasharray: 10px;
}

.square {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  animation: good-roll 2s infinite ease-in-out both;
  position: relative;
  --left: 1;
}

@keyframes good-dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 1, 10;
  }
  50% {
    stroke-dasharray: 1, 5;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 1, 10;
  }
}

@keyframes bad-dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 1px, var(--stroke-dasharray);
  }
  50% {
    stroke-dasharray: 1px, calc(var(--stroke-dasharray) / 2);
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 1px, var(--stroke-dasharray);
  }
}

@keyframes good-roll {
  0% {
    left: calc(var(--left) * 1px);
  }
  50% {
    left: calc(var(--left) * 50px);
  }
  100% {
    left: calc(var(--left) * 1px);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="25 25 50 50">
  <circle class="good" cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="none"/>
</svg>
<svg viewBox="25 25 50 50">
  <circle class="bad" cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="none"/>
</svg>
<div class="square"></div>
```

Comment: I don't think they are mandatory, we can use calc() without unit

Comment: probably for some specific cases but I still disagree that in general we need units inside calc(). It depends on what the property can accept as value. This for example is valid: https://jsfiddle.net/umkhgyar/1/

Comment: another example with opacity that should work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/umkhgyar/2/

Comment: Indeed, using px unit solve the problem. But nowhere in documentation we can see stroke-dasharray used with any unit: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dasharray. The attribute accept unitless values, so in my opinion it should work without unit in animation.

Comment: It's worth understanding the difference between what you should do as a best practice, and what seems to work in a limited test case in just one or two browsers.  Robert is giving good advice, if you want to avoid future problems listen to the advice of an expert.